# Where can I read about DER certificate structure - fields and its registered values?

Tags: certificates, asn.1

Where is an official documentation for ASN1 structure and values of x509 certs?

Using OpenSSL command like `openssl asn1parse -in server.der -inform DER` I can see how the cert is structured, but, for example, value `OBJECT :sha256WithRSAEncryption` is HEX `2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 0B`, or countryName identifier is `55 04 06` - where are all this values documented?

Comment: These links might help you, rfc5280 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280) and ASN.1 and DER (https://letsencrypt.org/docs/a-warm-welcome-to-asn1-and-der/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASN.1 is defined by the International Telecommunication Union (the ITU). ASN.1 stands for Abstract Syntax Notation One, and is a schema definition language. DER, as well as its base form BER, are serialization formats of the data defined by the ASN.1-specified schema.

ASN.1 and DER/CER/BER are specified in ITU-T-X series standards, available at the [official ITU website](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X/e). Information about OIDs are available at http://oid-info.com/

Comment: I find Burt Kaliski's 1993 [_A Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER_](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html) as useful as ever.